# User experience bug on Twitter

Tags: multithreading, twitter

On Twitter:
If I reply to a thread, post it and then continue to scroll down and read the thread, as soon as I get to my own contribution, the scroll flicks back to the top. I can only cure this by refreshing the whole page, thereby losing my place in the thread.
This is reproducible every time.
Anyone else?
Any solutions?

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to programming.

Comment: Fair enough! I probably (deffo!) asked in the wrong place! Was I thinking of 'stack exchange'? Carry on, as you were!